# Use the regular expression feature of Oracle to find a double vowel sequence, eg. ‘ie’, ‘ee’, ‘oa’

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Use the regular expression feature of Oracle to find all movies whose title includes a word with a double vowel sequence, ‘ie’, ‘ee’, ‘oa’. I know it's something to do with the like clause but the order of the code is what's giving me trouble. Any help appreciated.

"table_name movies"

```
SELECT *  
FROM movies
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (title, ‘ie’, ‘ee’, ‘oa’);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have identified the correct function, but it looks like you don't know how to formulate regular expressions. You should read up about regular expressions in a general sense, outside the context of Oracle. There are various dialects of regex, but once you learn one dialect, it should be easy switch to others.

For your specific Oracle question:

```
select * from movies where regexp_like( title, '[aeiou]{2}' );
```

Comment: I think the ".*" are unnecessary. A regexp should match if the expression is anywhere inside the string.

Comment: @eaolson - you are correct, thanks. I've edited the answer to the simpler form. My mind was thinking about the standard LIKE operator that must match the entire string.

Comment: It seem to me that this should work but I am getting no rows in return, puzzling

Comment: scratch that, my table is in all caps lol thanks for the help dbenham

Answer (score 0):

This will only work for ms-sql. Leaving the answer in case anyone need it.

```
where title like '%[aeiou][aeiou]%'
```

Comment: What kind of Oracle syntax is that? I'm 99% sure that cannot work, but I have been out of touch with Oracle for a few years. I'm very tempted to down vote.

Comment: Yeah that's sort of a mix of Oracle's wildcard operator % and regexp.

Comment: @dbenham I assumed this was a standard way of writing this syntax. It works for ms-sql. I now realize it doesn't work for Oracle

Comment: This won't work in Oracle ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions007.htm#BABGDGIH))

Comment: @CheranShunmugavel would you care to elaborate ? This page looks very professionel and official. I am just quoting it. You downvoted me for refering to oracle's official homepage. I think that is a bit harsh.

Comment: `'([aeiou])\1'` will only match vowel pairs where it's the same vowel: aa, ee, ii, oo, uu. But the poster also wants ie, oa.

Comment: @Barmar ok, thank you very much i didn't realize the example only took pairs.